# how can i combine two queries to get result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hi all i am trying to get a grand child and child from parent .i have two queries one is to get a child(test) from parent and another query is to get a grand child(test) from parent(course

below is my tables:

table object_data:

```
obj_id | type | title 
---    |------|------
3217   |crs   |it 
3221   |grp   |xyz 
3228   |tst   |test 
3264   |tst   |test3
```

table object_reference:

```
 ref_id | obj_id 
    ---    |---------
    337    |3217       
    338    |3221      
    343    |3228 
    371    |3264
```

table tree:

```
 tree | child | parent 
    ---  |-------|------
    1    |338    |337 
    2    |343    |338 
    3    |371    |337
```

from above three tables i need to display like id 3217 has id 3228 and 3264(need to display only type "tst") i need a query .i am able to write a query for only child id not for grand child .any one help to sort out this

and below is my code for query

controller:

```
 if ($course) 

        $users_query="SELECT o.title as course_title,u.*,u.usr_id,o.obj_id FROM object_data o,usr_data u,obj_members rn WHERE o.obj_id=rn.obj_id AND u.usr_id=rn.usr_id AND o.type='crs'  AND o.obj_id=$course";
    //dd($users_query);


    $user_records = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($users_query);
    //dd($user_records);
    $final_data = [];

    foreach($user_records as $user)
    {
        if(!$course)
            continue;
        $user_course_query = "SELECT *, (select obj_id FROM `object_reference` obr WHERE obr.ref_id = t.child) as final_reference FROM object_data o,object_reference r,tree t  WHERE o.obj_id=r.obj_id AND t.parent=r.ref_id AND o.obj_id=$course";

               $user_course_query =
    "
              SELECT *,(select obj_id FROM object_reference f WHERE f.ref_id = e.child and f.ref_id=e.child) as final_reference FROM object_data a JOIN object_reference b ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id JOIN tree c ON b.ref_id = c.parent JOIN object_reference d ON c.child = d.ref_id JOIN tree e ON d.ref_id = e.parent JOIN object_reference f ON e.child = f.ref_id JOIN object_data g ON f.obj_id = g.obj_id JOIN tst_tests s ON g.obj_id=s.obj_fi JOIN tst_active t ON s.test_id=t.test_fi JOIN usr_data u ON u.usr_id=t.user_fi and u.usr_id=$user->usr_id and  a.obj_id=$course GROUP by a.obj_id" ;
        // dd($user_course_query);
        //$this->db->escape($user_course_query);
            $user_course_records = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($user_course_query);
    // dd($user_course_records);

        foreach($user_course_records as $course_data)
        { 
            $final_reference=$course_data->final_reference;

            $user_tests_query = "SELECT u.firstname,o.*,ta.*,tpr.workingtime,tcr.mark_official,(tcr.reached_points/tcr.max_points)*100 as result,v.value FROM usr_data u,object_data o,tst_active ta,tst_tests tt ,tst_pass_result tpr, tst_result_cache tcr,udf_text v WHERE u.usr_id=ta.user_fi AND tt.obj_fi=o.obj_id AND v.usr_id=u.usr_id AND ta.test_fi=tt.test_id  AND ta.active_id=tpr.active_fi AND tcr.active_fi=ta.active_id AND v.field_id='2'   AND u.usr_id=$user->usr_id AND  o.obj_id = $final_reference ".$date_condition;


        $user_tests = $this->base_model->executeSelectQuery($user_tests_query);

            foreach($user_tests as $test)
            {

                $dta['usr_id']      = $user->usr_id;
                $dta['firstname']       = $user->firstname;
                $dta['email']           = $user->email;
                $dta['matriculation']   = $user->matriculation;
                $dta['approve_date']    = $user->approve_date;
                $dta['department']  = $user->department;


                $final_data[] = $dta;
            }
        }

    }
    $data['records'] = $final_data;
```

hi all i am trying to get a grand child and child from parent .i have two queries one is to get a child(test) from parent and another query is to get a grand child(test) from parent(course
hi all i am trying to get a grand child and child from parent .i have two queries one is to get a child(test) from parent and another query is to get a grand child(test) from parent(course

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: And be specific what is the problem. Is the sql code, is the php?

Comment: beside the fact that you should never ever do sql queries like these - whats you desired output ?

Comment: actually from the above three tables in need to display an out put like parent  id 3217 has id 3228 and 3264 that means need to display child and grand child like 3217(it) has test and test3

Comment: from the above code am getting only grand child am unable to get child as well

Comment: The problem here is the SQL, please read about the `JOIN` keyword so you can do it all in a single query. This is the relational Database main purpose.